# how to implement a dynamic width div with the parties fixed size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

how to create a div that be fix from both sides (responsive). something like this:

```
                               Screen (big)
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                |
|....20px.....______________________________________....20px.....|
|            |                                      |            |
|            |                 div                  |            |
|            |______________________________________|            |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+




                Screen (small)
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                            |
|....20px.....__________________....20px.....|
|            |                  |            |
|            |       div        |            |
|            |__________________|            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

It should be noted that my focus is just on `left` and `right` side.

Now is implementation of this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3882tctr/)

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  background: orange;
}
.child {
  height: 100px;
  background: #663399;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ow ! the point is I should create two nested div, and the child is my goal. thanks

Comment: It is strange that you did not use of `width`!

Comment: I don't need to use width. Divs are 100% wide by default.

Comment: In fact you can just add padding to the body if you don't want to nest divs - https://jsfiddle.net/3882tctr/1/

Comment: please check out the answer of @lance, that is great.

Answer (score 2):

No wrapping necessary:

```html
<style>
div
{
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin: 0 20px;
}
</style>

<div>Hi!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after? http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/xGJPyX
Wrap your div with a parent div which has 20px padding left and right

HTML

```
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="main-div"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div-wrap{
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
}
.main-div{
  background-color:pink;
  min-height:100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to archieve, probably you want to build a more complex layout?

Just set the margin with the desired margins and use a normal div (display: block). Probably you will need to remove `padding` and `margin` from the `body` and `html` elements. E.g:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="contents">...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.contents {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/471qsbuh/) for an interactive example.